# What is the significance of weapons? Why do gods carry multiple weapons?

Tags: gods, weapon, darshan

Every Hindu God carries multiple weapons like Trishul, Chakra, Gada, Pharsha, Danda, Sword or Bow. The same god in different Murthis (statue) carries different weapons.

If one weapon is powerful enough to kill the demon, why do gods carry  multiple weapons?

I have heard that darshan of these weapons is equally important as each of them bless us with protection, peace, wealth, knowledge, health etc. If it's true I want to know the significance of prominent weapons and the way to worship them.

Comment: OP, do you have any source for your claims about 'darshan' of weapon?

Comment: You see, some demons or *asuras* already behold strong, rare weapons with them. The architect of Gods, Vishwakarma, made new and better weapons to destroy the demon. I hope this has helped you a bit.

Comment: Those weapons are for the upliftment and give confidence to suffering souls. For the Lord they are part of his nature and glory.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.chakranews.com/powerful-spiritual-and-physical-weapons-from-ancient-hindu-texts/2762) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astra_%28weapon%29) are some of the weapons which were used by ancient Hindu Gods.

And about their worship there is something called [Shastra Puja](http://www.drikpanchang.com/navratri/durga-puja/ayudha-puja-date-time.html) , [Ayudha Puja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayudha_Puja) or some parts of North India its [Vishwakarma Puja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishwakarma_Day).
On these days worship of weapons or Implements which are used by the people with different profession is undertaken so as to protect them with the instrument which they are associated with.

In Kerala there is an ancient martial art named [Kalaripayattu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalaripayattu) in this also the weapons are worshipped before they start the battle and these weapons are placed in particular puja room where they face East direction according to [Vastu Shastra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vastu_Shastra). Mostly their guardian deity are an avatar of Bhagavathi (Devi/Shakti), Kali, Shiva, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've asked darshan of which weapon benefits the devotee in what way? like darshan of sword removes ignorance and gives knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer one weapon at a time for want of correct references.

**Trishul:**
Refer [SREE PADA SREEVALLABHA CHARITHAMRUTHAM](http://www.sreepadasreevallabhapithapuram.org/charitramrutam.html)

Siva has the ‘**Trishul**’ as the main weapon. Trishul has three sharp spikes
at the end. They will be in the form of ‘agni’ flames. Those three will unite at the base and
the stem of Trishul will be a single hand. Those three spikes indicate three qualities,
Satva, Rajas and Tamo gunas. The combined form is really beyond these three qualities.
There is another meaning. The breath flows through the nerves ‘Ida and Pingala’ and
reaches the place between the two eye brows. The center, where the three nerves Ida,
Pingala and Sushumna reach is called ‘Triveni’ sangamam. This is the center of Brahma
Jnana. This is the inner meaning of Trishul.

'Demon' in this context is imbalance of Trigunas.