# Why do Hindu Gods carry weapons?

Tags: gods, symbolism, weapon

I always wonder why Hindu Gods carry weapons. I mean they are "Gods", why do they need weapons?

Comment: They don't need weapons. However they carry them just to assure the worshiper that they are in control and will take care of everything. After all, in the initial stages of bhakti, the devotees worship God out of fear and need for protection, thus the form of the deity gives a sort of assurance and keeps the mind from fears.

Comment: See http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-the-significance-of-weapons

Comment: Journalist and economist S.Gurumurthy once jokingly said that Hindus gave all their weapons to their gods and remained in peace while the Abrahamic God gave weapons into his poeple and they fight with each other.

Comment: Related: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-the-significance-of-weapons

Comment: Because they like fighting every time .... ;) Actually they hold powers and they can control the weapons and also reposnibilities are performed by them.

Comment: Gods with weapons are human concepts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I feel the terminology of "God" is unsuitable. Unfortunately in English there is no proper translation of Devtā. Deity is closer.

In Hinduism devās are seen as friends and guides and hence human qualities were projected on them. This can be seen throughout the Rig Veda. Hinduism evolved from tribal roots and also assimilated tribal cultures into it. The deities are thus portrayed as how a human helper or a protector would be - with weapons.

The Rig Vedic people didn’t worship in temples but did in fire altars. Given that temples were a later development, lots of metaphorical and philosophical ideas had developed behind the iconography.

In the book "Hindu Iconology - The study of the symbolism and meaning of Icons", Pandit Sri Rama Ramanuja Achari outlines the symbolic meanings behind many aspects of Hindu iconography.

Here are some of them:

[image: Iconography 1]
[image: Iconography 2]
[image: Iconography 3]
[image: Iconography 4]

For further information on Hindu iconography refer to [this](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/hindu_iconography_1.pdf) e-book.

Sometimes even the weapons themselves are given human form. For example Sudarshana Chakra is given anthropomorphic form and known as Chakkrath Azhwar in Tamil.

Comment: It is up to you to take Ramanuja Achari's words or not. I would trust Aacharyas & Gurus. Hinduism is not a book based religion, so one needn't be too particular about finding a quote from the 'books' when an Aacharya has said it. Again this is just my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely okay to cite the words of an Acharya on this site.  By the way, you should be wary of Rama Ramanujachari; he's a Sri Vaishnava Acharya, but his views are quite heterodox.  He calls his views "Metkalai", because he has disagreements with both Thenkalais and Vadakalais.  He doesn't even believe in the existence of Vaikuntha!  I wouldn't be surprised if he believed that Vishnu doesn't even have a physical form, and that it's all just symbolism.