# Symbols of mercy in Hinduism?

Tags: symbolism

What are the possible symbols of mercy and/or compassion in Hinduism? As always answers with supporting references are appreciated.

Comment: By symbols do you mean icons, images, art? See if [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10114/2995) is useful.