# What is the significance of the weapons and other items held by the Lord Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, weapon, symbolism

Lord Vishnu holds a Disc (Chakra), Conch (Sankha), Komidi Gadha, and also holds other elements like a lotus in his hand.

Is there any explanation in scriptures of why Lord Vishnu holds these particular weapons?

Comment: You are asking very good questions, Jai Shri Hari :)

Comment: Its symbolic, When softness (lotus) doesnt work, you use hard methods (weapons)

Comment: @ABcDexter Thanks brother . Jai shri Hari.. :)

Comment: @AmitSaxena but brother , I don't think so, it's perfect answer.

Comment: As per my logic I can say that Disc and conch is play very important role to creation of the universe and each any every thing, like  you can take example of wheel, and also take example of the each and every planet's motion is like in circular way.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Yes true, thats why I commented rather than posting an answer.

Comment: and I got some knowledge about conch from one of my architecture's friend , he said like the galaxy was created in shape of conch and in the architecture world, the diameter of conch as considered to make any things, like if you take the Coke bottle/ water bottle's mouth (upper part) diameter, they take Conch's diameter for create each and every things, I don't know whether this thing is right or wrong, but he told me like that even-thogh he is clever and very huge knowledge of Architecture.

Comment: So, I think that something is related to Disc and Conch for creation of world and other thing , but I want perfect answer if it is in our Scriputers,

Comment: You may find symbolism from [1](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/hinduism/vishnu.asp), [2](http://www.mailerindia.com/god/hindu/index.php?vish2) and [3](http://www.bvihar.com/?p=856).

Comment: Related: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-is-the-significance-of-weapons

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lord Vishnu carries all the tattvas in the world in the form of his weapons. Each weapon and ornament is a symbolism for each tattva.

The symbolism and significance of them are described in 7 verses in [Vishnu Purana Chapter 22](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp057.htm):

> The glorious Hari wears the pure soul of the world, undefiled, and void of qualities, as the Kaustubha gem. The chief principle of things (Pradhána) is seated on the eternal, as the Srivatsa mark. Intellect abides in Mádhava, in the form of his mace. The lord (Íśwara) supports egotism (Ahankára) in its twofold division, into elements and organs of sense, in the emblems of his conch-shell and his bow. In his hand Vishńu holds, in the form of his discus, the mind, whose thoughts (like the weapon) fly swifter than the winds. The necklace of the deity Vaijayantí, composed of five precious gems, is the aggregate of the five elemental rudiments. Janárddana bears, in his numerous shafts, the faculties both of action and of perception. The bright sword of Achyuta is holy wisdom, concealed at some seasons in the scabbard of ignorance. In this manner soul, nature, intellect, egotism, the elements, the senses, mind, ignorance, and wisdom, are all assembled in the person of Hrishikeśa. Hari, in a delusive form, embodies the shapeless elements of the world, as his weapons and his ornaments, for the salvation of mankind.

So, each weapon or ornament corresponds to a tattva.

- Kaustubha Gem  : Soul (Purusha)
- Sri Vatsa mark : Pradhana Prakruti
- Kaumodaki Mace : Intellect (Buddhi)
- Sharga bow    : Egotism (Tamasa Ahankára) of elements
- Panchajanya conch : Egotism (Saatvika Ahankára) of sense organs
- Sudarshana Chakra : The mind (manas).
- Vaijayanti Mala : Five elements of rudiments (pancha bhoota)
- Arrows : Sense organs
- Nandaka sword : Knowledge (Gnana)
- Sheath of the sword : Ignorance (Agnana)

Comment: Well explained !!!

Comment: which of these is Rajasika Ahamkara?

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri, rajasa ahamkara, in the 24 tattva categorization, just acts as an initiator, it is not subdivided into indriyas/tanmatras.

Comment: Yes symbolic mean should interruptedd Gajenjendra is us one got in the crocodile pond of samsara only Sri Hari s grace will release this from crocodile he needs only our saranagathi sisupala is our ashuya on good things when in your field somebody your contemporary got credit for work means one should appreciate instead of critising Krishna chackra need in both case to cut asunder  Sudharshan may mean vishnushasra nama by reciting on this we can cut all those

Comment: @PrasannaR so you mean the events of Mahabharata are symbolical as some of the the kriyayogis claim and they never happened in reality? But the Vaishnava Acharyas never seem to say this

Comment: I was saying should also be interrupted otherwise no scripture makes sense

Comment: Beautiful explanation, never knew Vishnu Purana had such a wonderful exposition.