# Information on list of Sri Vishnu's weapons requested

Tags: vishnu, identification-request, weapon

Sri Madhvacharya, the propagator of Dvaita siddanta and the Brahma sampradaya,  has authored a book called TantrasArasaMgraha.

In the same book, under adhyAya 4, verse 18-20, Sri Madhvacharya lists the set of weapons which Sri Vishnu holds. There, Acharya mentions that the list weapons is not limited to the below;

1. Shanka and Chakra - Conch and Disc
2. Gadha & Padma - Mace and Flower
3. Khadga & Kheta - Sword and Shield
4. SharaNga & shara - Bow and arrows
5. Musala & Vajra - Club and a weapon made of Diamond (Indra's weapon)
6. Hala & shUla - Plough (Balarama's Weapon) and Trident
7. pAsha & Ankusha - Noose and Goad
8. bhindipAla & Pattasa - Javelin (like the Subramanya's Shakti) and ??
9. Varamudra & Abhayamudra - Mudras bestowing boons and dispelling fears
10. Agni & Tatvamudra  - Fire and Hand displaying Tatva Mudra
11. AkshamAlA & Pustaka - Rosary Beads and a Book

I am familiar of the first 2, they being a common mention in many texts. I am aware of the next 2 (3 & 4) from the Bhagavatha. The rest are news to me.

Is there any other scripture that talks about Sri Vishnu holding / using these weapons, specifically the Agama texts?

PS- i am aware of a various interpretations of deities holding weapons, or all these weapons being surrendered to one deity by others. I request that such interpretations not be a part of the answer unless it is backed by scripture such as [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12458/what-is-the-significance-of-the-weapons-elements-held-by-the-lord-vishnu?rq=1). Seeking more info on the same lines.

Comment: Yes, there are different forms of Vishnu holding different weapons besides Shankha and chakra. There are totally 24 forms described from Agamas. For Aniruddha form, see [Why does Vishnu's thousand-armed Aniruddha form carry the equipment of a student?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6534/5212)